# Regex that can match and return a part of text while remove the rest to make gender specific text possible

Tags: javascript, regex

Don't know what to try. I keep getting these closed, because I'm told it is not explained, not specific, whatever.  Perhaps rather than shutting this down instantly, someone on this site can be kind enough to help me?  Is that possible without shutting down the thread instantly and before anyone can even ask a question?

In Javascript (Google App Scripts).

String="I want [him/her] to go to [his/her] side when [he/she] is done."

What is the regex that I'm trying to figure out would allow the result to be: "I want him to go to his side when he is done."

The common factor will be [.../...]

Since the second half of this question appears too be confusing and I keep getting the question closed before anyone has a chance to comment....I'll ask almost the same exact question again in a second post.  You might guess what my follow up question will be, but apparently that is not appropriate to ask...I'll give extra brownie points if you know what I'm going to ask and can answer it.

Comment: I don't know the close reasons from before, but one thing that we ask people asking questions to do is to show what they've attempted in their question. If you've given some regex code a shot already, it'd help to see what you've already tried. Think of it this way; this site is more about "help me figure this out," and less about "solve this problem for me."

Comment: That might be possible if I really understood regex.  I learn by seeing what others do.  I typically come to this site and find a solution that is close enough to what I need.  In this case, I wasn't able to find something close.  The best I can figure is to match all bracketed string, remove bracket, split on the slash and return either 0,1 from that, but it is pretty clunky.  I'm assuming there is a regex way.  By seeing the results, I'm better able to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern, as represented in a `RegExp` is:

```
Starting [ = \[     (escaped since `[` has special meaning)
Option A   = [^\/]* (any character except slash, repeated 0-to-many times)
Slash      = \/     (escaped as above to differentiate from a RegExp literal terminator)
Option B   = [^\]]* (any character except a `]`, repeated 0-to-many times)
Closing ]  = ]
```

So putting this all together, with `()` for capture groups and adding a `g` flag for a global search, we get this mouthful since the string pattern we're looking for is *rife* with characters that are special to RegExp:

```
const pronounPattern = /\[([^\/]*)\/([^\]]*)]/g;
```

Now when we do a match/replace, because we have capture groups we get a pseudo-array, with index 0 being the full match, 1 being option A, and 2 being option B. This lets us now do a string replace. For example, if we always want to use option A, you can do:

```
const replaced = yourString.replace(pronounPattern, '$1');
```

The `$1` means "use capture group 1" which is in our case the first in the either/or group. Use `$2` for the second option. Putting this together in a function:

```
const MALE = 1;
const FEMALE = 2;
const pronounPattern = /\[([^\/]*)\/([^\]]*)]/g;
function replacePronounPlaceholders(str, option) {
  return str.replace(pronounPattern, '$' + option);
}

// Used like:

const replaced = replacePronounPlaceholders(
  "I want [him/her] to go to [his/her] side when [he/she] is done.",
  FEMALE);
```

Comment: Thank you for not only understanding a question that some appeared to be confused by, but also providing the exact elegance that I was trying to get to.

Comment: This was a little too greedy.  I think I figured it out with /\[([^\/?!\]]+)\/([^\]]+)]/g    It needed to cancel the match if the ] was found before a slash with the addition of ?!\].  There were some cases where [something] was incorrectly matched.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myStr = 'I want [him/her] to go to [his/her] side when [he/she] is done.';
var newStr = myStr.replace(/\[him\/her\]/g, "him").replace(/\[his\/her\]/g, "his").replace(/\[he\/she\]/g,"he");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is too literal.  I need to be able to place any male gender term or pronoun in the first half and have the result always show only the first half.  Conversely, when parsing for female, I would then have a result with each occurrence returning the second half

Answer (score 0):

not `javascript` but a regex solution with `sed`

```
$ echo "I want [him/her] to go to [his/her] side when [he/she] is done." | 
  sed -E 's_\[([^/]+)/[^]]+\]_\1_g'

I want him to go to his side when he is done.
```

you need to escape square brackets in literal use since it's a special regex char.

easy to change to get the second alternative

```
 ...  | sed -E 's_\[([^/]+)/([^]]+)\]_\2_g'

I want her to go to her side when she is done.
```

Comment: Don't know sed, but that looks close to what I'm trying to get, and you answered the bonus question I wasn't being allowed to ask!!  Well done!!!  I'll try to figure out what the javascript equivalent is to that, unless someone else knows what you're getting at and know the javascript code